# MATLAB printing to file empty graphs despite visible in plots

Tags: matlab, plot, save

The following code runs flawlessly on my machine:

```
x1 = [50, 100, 150];
y1 = [50, 100, 150];

plot(x1, y1);
axis([0 250 0 180]);

print('-dpdf', '-r100', 'C:\file');
```

I both see the correct graph in the appearing window and in that written to file.

However, I have 28 sets of ~214 actual (x, y) data that appear to bother MATLAB; it WILL correctly display the graph in the appearing window but writes an empty graph (with axis but no data) to file.

My data features quite a few NaN values which don't seem to perturb the visible, windowed graph.

Attempting to file -> save as -> pdf in the Figure window of the successfully graphed (but not saved) plot results in a completely blank saved file (even when having removed the print attempt from the code). It does this on my Windows 7 machine, MATLAB R2015a 64-bit.

Am I overworking MATLAB or something?
Why is it able to display but not write to file my plot?

I have saved the data to file by

```
csvwrite('C:\TEST_X.txt', x1);
csvwrite('C:\TEST_Y.txt', y1);
```

available [here (x1)](http://textuploader.com/xwqx) and [here (y1)](http://textuploader.com/xwqg) .

Comment: Can you show the code for your actual plotting? Or is it the same as your example apart for the `x1` and `y1`?

Comment: Yup, it's precisely the same (besides the alternate `x1`, `y1` definitions)

Comment: Can you modify your example `x1` and `y1` to reproduce the problem? Maybe by adding `NaN`'s? What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the export_fig submission. It aims to export figures just as they appear on screen. Link: www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Comment: Saving your example data `x1` and `y1` works on my computer (Win 7, R2014a). Can you please add OS and MATLAB version? Does printing to eps or ps work?

Comment: @hbaderts The massive data I've linked to? :| I've added those details. What exactly are eps and ps (excuse my naivety)?

Comment: @AntiEarth .ps and .eps are Post Script format and Encapsulated Post Script format. Shortly, it is vector graphics, which will give you much nicer plots than bitmaps when zooming in. However, they also takes up more memory. I think that the reason for hbaderts question is that this kind of graphics does not work exactly as bitmaps and thus it is possible it will work better.